# Resigning First Responder and View End Editing methods causing app to crash

Tags: ios, swift

I have a couple of textFields on the view, the return key on first textfield makes the second one the first responder which works fine. And pressing the return key on the second textfield should dismiss the keyboard. It was working fine before I updated to the latest version of Xcode.

And now I get the following error every time I use either of these methods:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1863be084 0x1969fc0e4 0x1862a7850 0x10013e7bc 0x10012dda4 0x10012e03c 0x18ac6cab0 0x18abe9e84 0x18ac6c6bc 0x18acc8dac 0x10012e338 0x10012e3c4 0x18ad3cc60 0x18ad00acc 0x18ad12684 0x18b2a4858 0x18aec6b00 0x18aec62ec 0x18ad009e4 0x18b2a4858 0x18ac5474c 0x18ad007b0 0x18ad0042c 0x18acffde4 0x18acfea80 0x18acfdaa8 0x18acfca8c 0x18acfc414 0x18ab68a98 0x18728a7f0 0x186376324 0x1863755c8 0x186373678 0x1862a1664 0x18f3db5a4 0x18aba64f8 0x1001430ec 0x10014312c 0x19706aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

This is my code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField : UITextField) -> Bool {
    var nextTag : Int = textField.tag + 1
    if(nextTag == 2) {
        var nextResponder : UIResponder = textField.superview!.viewWithTag(nextTag)!
        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true
    } else {
        if(textField.isFirstResponder()) { self.mainView!.endEditing(true) }
        return true

    }
}
```

This is an action from a button, its throws the same error:

```
@IBAction func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

I have looked everywhere and cannot figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After every update of Xcode I do the following steps:

- Product --> (hold down Alt key) Clean Build Folder
- Product --> Clean
- Window --> Organizer --> Delete derived data

Then rebuild the project